# Instalar controlsFX en netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javafx

Quiero utilizar los nuevos controles controlsFX que he descargado del fichero [controlsfx-8.40.10](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-8.40.10.zip) de la página oficial y lo he instalado en SceneBuilder aunque algunos controles no aparecen como el `PopOver`

También he descargado el [repositorio](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/get/5d434167241f.zip) y lo he abierto en netbeans como un nuevo proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación he abierto el sub proyecto 'controlsfx' y he copiado los 'Source Packages' a mi proyecto particular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi proyecto es un miniprograma que sólo muestra un controlFX llamado `CustomTextField`:

```
package pruebacontrolsfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.CustomTextField;

public class PruebaControlsFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CustomTextField customField = new CustomTextField();
        customField.setPromptText("Introduce texto");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(customField); // genera un error ¿por qué?       
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo aparece un error justo cuando añado el control `CustomTextField` a un contenedor `StackPane`

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción puede ser agregar el `.jar` a tu proyecto, ve a la página oficial http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/

Descarga la versión actual

> **Getting ControlsFX**
>
> For users of JavaFX 8u40 and greater, [download ControlsFX
>   8.40.10](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/).

Simplemente descomprime el archivo el cual contendrá varios .jar, el que necesitamos es **`controlsfx-{version}.jar`**

En tu proyecto, abre el folder Libraries, da clic y botón derecho y selecciona la opción `Add JAR/Folder`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realizando este procedimiento ahora puedes agregar sin problema el `import`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y poner en funcionamiento tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta no está aportando nada nuevo puesto que en la pregunta ya se están siguiendo estos mismos pasos pero el problema es otro.

Comment: Hola por eso es bueno que al realizar una pregunta se indiquen este tipo de datos. Porque muchos usuarios escriben una pregunta la cual puede tener infinidad de respuestas. Con las imágenes das mucha más información lo cual es perfecto. Dame unos segundos para ayudarte con este problema.

Comment: Puede ser correcto lo que haces, agregar 'Source Packages' como proyecto, pero debes construir y agregar este proyecto como librería. Sin embargo realiza el procedimiento que agrego en mi respuesta, agregar el .jar y con eso no debes tener problema. =)

Comment: Gracias. Al final es más sencillo que todo el embrollo que hacía. Funciona.